# Retrieve a document from a collection by field in Firestore with REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, google-cloud-firestore, axios, crud

I'm trying to get a **Firestore** document by one of its field values in **Node.js**, with **Axios**. My document in Firestore looks like this (belonging to my collection **'users'**):

```
userName: 'John Doe'
userEmail: 'john.doe@example.com'
```

I know I can **get all the collection** with a code like this:

```
axios.get(`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECTIDHERE>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTIONNAME>`)
     .then(response => { 
         console.log(response); 
        })
        .catch(error => { 
            console.log(error); 
        });
```

Also, I do know that I can **get a document of the collection by its ID** like this:

```
axios.get(`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECTIDHERE>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTIONNAME>/<DOCID>`)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

However, like the question says, I want to search in the whole collection to retrieve the document that has  **userEmail** field **'john.doe@example.com'**.

According to Jean Snyman in its [**blog**](https://www.jeansnyman.com/posts/google-firestore-rest-api-examples/), the axios **method**, should have a **structuredQuery**.

His example shows something like this:

```
axios.post('https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECTIDHERE>/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery', 
        { structuredQuery: 
            { from: [
                { collectionId: 'posts' 
            }
        ], 
        orderBy: [
            { field: 
                { fieldPath: 'created' 
            }, direction: 'DESCENDING' }
        ], select: { fields: 
            [
                { fieldPath: 'title' }, 
                { fieldPath: 'summary' }, 
                { fieldPath: 'category' }, 
                { fieldPath: 'created' }
            ] 
        }, 
        where: { 
            compositeFilter: { 
                filters: [
                    { fieldFilter: { 
                        field: { 
                            fieldPath: 'published' 
                        }, 
                            op: 'EQUAL', 
                            value: { 
                                booleanValue: true 
                            } 
                        } 
                    }
                ], op: 'AND' 
            } 
        }, 
            limit: 4 
            } 
        }
        ).then(res => { 
            console.log(res) 
        })
        .catch(error => {
```

Trying to follow his logic, I came with a code like this:

```
await axios.get(`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectID}/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery/key=${key}`,
      {
        structuredQuery:
        {
          from: [
            {
              collectionId: collection
            }
          ],
          where: {
            compositeFilter: {
              filters: [
                {
                  fieldFilter: {
                    field: {
                      fieldPath: 'userEmail'
                    },
                    op: 'EQUAL',
                    value: {
                      stringValue: 'john.doe@example.com'
                    }
                  }
                }
              ], op: 'AND' 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

However I retrieve an empty object, what indicates me I'm doing something wrong. Well, my interest is to **retrieve the documents by the mentioned field**. If you came up with a solution without **Axios** and **structuredQuery**, works great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about axios, looks good compared with the example you showed. But maybe you use different version, try checking docs again and upgrading libraries.

You can also use [official Node library](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/) to query by field value as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#node.js_1).

```
const usersRef = db.collection('users');

// Create a query against the collection
const queryRef = usersRef.where('userEmail', '==', 'john.doe@example.com');
const snapshot = await queryRef.get();
```

Comment: Besides the fact that the example you shared says I should enable the Rest API I don't actually see any reference in the sample making reference to it. The example shows a custom Rest API example, but not the [Official Firestore Rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api).

Comment: Hey! did you tried Emil's approach? did it worked for you?